# Why is this select2 control not populating with dynamic data through an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a template, I have:

```
    <div ng-controller="projectListController as projects" class="pull-right" id="projectListDropDown">

        <select ui-select2 id="projectListDD" placeholder="All" class="width240" ng-model="projects.projectSelection">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in projects.projectList" value="{{item.WebsiteName}}">{{item.WebsiteName}}</option>
        </select>

    </div>
```

I want to populate the dropdown list from `projectList` below:

```
app.controller('projectListController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$log', 'abstractDataFactory', 'customUIFunctions', 'globalContainer',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $log, abstractDataFactory, customUIFunctions, globalContainer) {

       dashboardGlobals = this.dashboardGlobals = globalContainer.dashboardGlobals;
        var dataFactory = new abstractDataFactory("/odata/ProjectList");
        var projectController = new abstractDataFactory("/Projects/ChangeCurrentProject")  // load up projectDashboardDTO

        this.selectProjectPlaceholder = "Loading Projects . . .";

        this.filterItems = [
          { id: 1, text: 'Item1' },
          { id: 2, text: 'Item2' },
          { id: 3, text: 'Item3' },
          { id: 4, text: 'Item4' }
        ];

        this.projectList = [];

        // TODO; keep a global list of projects
        // Get a list of current projects
        dataFactory.getList("")   // no parameters
            .success(function (result) {
                this.projectList = result.value; //<- array of objects is returned
                dashboardGlobals.projectList = result.value;  
                this.selectProjectPlaceholder = "Select a project . . . "

                $("#projectListSelection").select2({ width: '240' });
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                customUIFunctions.showError("Data Error - Unable to Load Project List"); // use default error message
                console.log("data error");
            });
```

I have confirmed that there is data in `result.value` but the list remains blank.

However, when I use `projects.filterItems` in the `ng-repeat`, (along with `id` and `text` field names) the list is populated.

I also want the changed value to be globally accessible in Angular, so I injected my own `globalContainer` service into this controller, and whenever the page is refreshed, I want to ensure the selected value remains consistent, rather than resetting.

**-- UPDATE --**

The problem seems to be in the `.success` area, `this.projectList` is `undefined`.  If I do `var projectList = this.projectList = []` no error, but this doesn't seem right.

So the issue is with trying to define the variables after the fact, and using `Controller as...`.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading something about half way down the page, [here](http://discuss.codeschool.io/t/shaping-up-with-angularjs-why-use-this-instead-of-scope/4801/18), and a bit more further understanding about the difference between `$scope` and `this`, in how they work in `.success`, I declared `vm` as a top-level `this`:

```
    var vm = this;
    vm.dashboardGlobals = globalContainer.dashboardGlobals;
    var dataFactory = new abstractDataFactory("/odata/ProjectList");
    var projectController = new abstractDataFactory("/Projects/ChangeCurrentProject")  // load up projectDashboardDTO

    vm.projectList = [];
.
.
.

        dataFactory.getList("")   // no parameters
            .success(function (result) {
                vm.projectList = result.value;
                vm.dashboardGlobals.projectList = result.value;
                vm.selectProjectPlaceholder = "Select a project . . . "
```