# How to retain a page's dropdown value across page loads when using MVC, C# and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Using C#, .Net, MVC5, AngularJS and the Select2 dropdown control, the dd is at the top of the layout, where a user can select a project.  The select2 control is populated as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363649/why-is-this-select2-control-not-populating-with-dynamic-data-through-an-angularj).

I created a global Angular service as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select2']);

    app.factory('globalContainer', function () {
        var globalContainer = {};

        globalContainer.dashboardGlobals = {
            userContext: Object(null),
            currentProject: Object(null),
            projectList: Object(null),
            testString: "Global Test String!!!"
        };

        return globalContainer;
    });
```

Setting the values in a controller as follows:

```
app.controller('projectListController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$log', 'abstractDataFactory', 'customUIFunctions', 'globalContainer',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $log, abstractDataFactory, customUIFunctions, globalContainer) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.dashboardGlobals = globalContainer.dashboardGlobals;
...


  vm.dashboardGlobals.projectList = result.value;
// make a restful call w/ data to set value on server side
```

The issue is that when I load up a new page, the values have been reset.  I am guessing if this was an Angular SPA, this would not be an issue, however this is not a SPA.

I can kick off a background call to a controller to populate a custom user context on the server (UserContext.Identity.CurrentProject) but abandoned this in favor of trying the Angular way.

Essentially, when the DD is changed, I want to set a globally-accessible object on the client-side (I can already do this on the server side).

What is the best way to approach this, given the current tech stack?

Suggestions please?

Comment: save the value either on server or localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ if you want to save it on the browser/client side.

Otherwise you will have to either post the info back to the server and populate it from a model or ViewBag.